# Getting corresponding eNum key for the value passed

Tags: javascript

```
var StateValue = {
    Unknown: 0,
    AL: 1,
    AK: 2,
    AZ: 3,
    AR: 4,
    CA: 5,
    CO: 6,
    CT: 7,
    DE: 8,
},
```

Now i need to get the enumValues.

```
function getKeyValue(stateVal) {
      For example 'AK'
    I need to get the corresponding value...    
}
```

Comment: well, in your title you say you need to get the key for the value passed, in your description you say you need the value, for the key passed. The accepted answer tells you how to get the value by the key. I came here cause I needed what you asked for in the title...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is simply:

```
var val = StateValue[stateVal];
```

You can access object properties with bracket notation.

I suggest to read [*MDC - Working with Objects*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: If i have to know the correspoding key by passing the value... 0 or 1.. what should i do

Comment: @John: You have two choices: Either loop over the properties and compare (which is slow), or create an array of keys (like you had in one of your previous questions).

Answer (score 37):

To answer the question in the title (in case someone comes for that), and not the one in the description, you can get the key by the value like this:

```
Object.keys(StateValue).find(
        key => StateValue[key] === 2
      )
```

this will return AK

Answer (score -2):

`var val = StateValue.AK` would return `2`, just like a regular ENUM